# How to check for missing values in a Time series in categories 1)Complete data for one day is missing and 2) Partial data for one day is missing

Tags: python, pandas, filter, time-series, missing-data

[image: Data looks like this]

I want the dates where there are missing values for complete day and also the days where there are missing values partially in a day.

I tried coding a loop for it but didn't work.

Comment: You can create a [date range](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.date_range.html) index with a 10 mins interval and compare it with the index of the dataframe. The intersection of the two indexes will give you all the missing dates. You can further process the missing indexes to determine which dates are completely or partially missing.

Comment: My data is already 10 mins apart. Can you type the code for the same so that you can be clearer?

Comment: `dt = pd.date_range(start='2021/05/01', periods=5, freq='10min')` will give you 5 data points at 10 mins interval. You can change it according to your need or other options such as range can be used which can be found in the shared link.

Comment: But my dates are not missing. The datetime index is complete. There are missing values in other columns like inverter 1 current or 2 voltage. I want to know if the missing values for those columns are completely or partially missing.

Comment: okay. Then you can try `df.loc[pd.isnull(df).any(1), :].index.values`. This will give you a list of the indexes which has missing (NaN) values.

Comment: I did that but how can I get different dataframes for partial missing values in a day and missing values in a complete day

Comment: Please share a sample of your data in text and not a screenshot, along with the code you have tried so far.